# help with access query

Tags: ms-access-2007

i have table `MyTbl` that contain `date1, date2, date3`

```
if date1=null i need that in field memo will be 'A'

elae if date2=null i need that in field memo will be 'B'

else if date3=null i need that in field memo will be 'C'
```

is it can made on access 2007 in query ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to do this with using IIF -

```
memo: IIf(IsNull([date1]=True),"A",IIf(IsNull([date2])=True,"B",IIf(IsNull([date3])=True,"C")))
```